Gangster shoots the guy up his butt and leaves to die slowly in dumpster
In the mid to late 1990's I saw a modern mob/gangster movie on a premium US cable TV station (HBO, Cinemax, etc). In which the gangsters (when they really didn't like somebody) would shoot the victim up the butt (with a .22?) and leave him to die slowly in a dumpster.  They had a word for the practice that was something weird like "buck-wheats" I think.  Does anybody know what movie that was?

Things to Do in Denver When You're Dead
